# AuraComponent not Displaying in Lighting in Preview

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, preview

I have a basic component that I have copied from the Aura Documentation

**Component**

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:input type="toggle" label="Basic option" name="input1"/>
    <lightning:input type="toggle" label="Required option" name="input2" checked="true" required="true"/>
    <lightning:input type="toggle" label="Disabled option" name="input3" checked="true" disabled="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Application**

```
<aura:application>
    <c:campingListItem/>
</aura:application>
```

### This is my display:

[image: MyResult]

---

### Expected Display:

[image: DocResult]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application you need to extend force:slds to import slds stylesheet

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:campingListItem/>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the quick response. Will mark as correct in 8min